# VUEX for VUE component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vuex, vuex-modules

I have a VUE component **JobComponent.vue** and I use **VUEX** to get data from **jobs.js**.
When I use this component in **Home.vue** I want to render it just for five times and in reverse mode, just the last 5 items starting with the last one. Now, it renders 7 times, because of the v-for from **JobComponent.vue**.

**JobComponent.vue**

```js
<div v-for="job in allJobs" :key="job.id" class="card">
    <div class="position">{{ job.position }}</div>
    <div class="department">{{ job.department }}</div>
    <div class="location">
      <span class="material-symbols-outlined">location_on</span>
      {{ job.location }}
    </div>
    <span class="material-symbols-outlined right-arrow">arrow_right_alt</span>
    <span @click="deleteJob" class="material-symbols-outlined right-arrow">delete</span>
  </div>
```

**Home.vue**

```js
  <div class="cards-container">
      <JobComponent />
  </div>
```

**jobs.js**

```json
const state = {
    jobs: [
        {
            position: "2",
            department: "2",
            location: "2",
            id: 2
          },
          {
            position: "3",
            department: "3",
            location: "3",
            id: 3
          },
          {
            position: "4",
            department: "4",
            location: "4",
            id: 4
          },
          {
            position: "5",
            department: "5",
            location: "5",
            id: 5
          },
          {
            position: "6",
            department: "6",
            location: "6",
            id: 6
          },
          {
            position: "7",
            department: "7",
            location: "7",
            id: 7
          }
    ]
};
```

Before VUEX I was fetching data in every *VUE* file that I need, I used v-for with *slice()* and *reverse()* method.

Comment: make a [getter](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html) to return the last 5 reversed jobs from your state to use with your `v-for`

Answer (score 1):

You can define `allJobs` as vuex getters and use computed property for what you want.

```
computed: {
  allJobs() {
    return this.$getters.allJobs.reverse().slice(0, 5);
  }
}
```

Comment: Or even further, you can define the getter with a parameter for slice and use it that way. 
[docs here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#method-style-access)

Comment: @homayounKh can you be more specific with the code example, I didn't understand very well. Thanks!

Comment: @kevsterdev my response was an example :) see [this link](https://gist.github.com/homayounKheiri/3cf0b255d55e20d0542fb3d9b2098a29)